# differentiability of function for pair of (m,n)

Tags: calculus

[image]

my doubt:

In this question, i think option B and option C are not correct. I need suggestions to decide which one from A and D are correct.

thanks.

Comment: Did you take the derivative and see what happens as $x \to 0$?

Comment: i tried by taking cases for (m,n). if m=1,n=2 removes B. if m=3,n=2 removed C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that 
$$\left|\frac{f_{m,n}(x)-f_{m,n}(0)}{x}\right|=\left|\frac{x^m\sin\frac{1}{x^n}-0}{x-0}\right|\leq|x|^{m-1}$$
Thus $f_{m,n}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ whenever $m>1$

Comment: so can we eliminate D by taking m=3,n=4 or not?

Comment: Yes, take any $m>1$ and take $n=m+1$, $f_{m,n}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but $m<n$